# Oracle SQL WITH clause select joined column

Tags: sql, oracle, join, with-clause

SQL:

```
WITH joined AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM table_a a 
    JOIN table_b b ON (a.a_id = b.a_id)
)
SELECT a_id 
FROM joined
```

returns invalid identifier.

How can you select joined column when using WITH clause? I have tried aliases, prefixing and nothing worked. I know I can use:

```
WITH joined AS (
    SELECT a.a_id 
    FROM table_a a 
    JOIN table_b b ON (a.a_id = b.a_id)
)
SELECT a_id 
FROM joined
```

but I need this alias to cover all fields.

Only way I managed to meet this condition is using:

```
WITH joined AS (
    SELECT a.a_id a_id_alias, a.*, b.* 
    FROM table_a a 
    JOIN table_b b ON (a.a_id = b.a_id) 
)
SELECT a_id_alias 
FROM joined
```

but it is not perfect solution...

Comment: I suppose this isn't your actual query, because the CTE is entirely unnecessary here.

Comment: Just minimalistic example of the functionality I need :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the effect of the `USING` clause when joining the tables.

When you join tables where the join columns have the same name (as it is the case with your example), the `USING` clause will return the join column only once, so the following works:

```
with joined as (
  select *
  from table_a a 
    join table_b b using (a_id)
)
select a_id
from joined;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e7e099/2

Comment: That's great...  I had no idea you could do that.

Comment: Not a lot of documentation on "using."  When I do a search, it comes up more often as a verb than a keyword.  I do see one potential pitfall -- it works nicely, even with more than a two-table join, but it can abstract where the actual join occurs if you are querying from three or more tables.  Still, a very nice tool to add to the repitoire and a "perfect" solution for the OP's question.

Comment: The `using` clause is documented in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2080416 (the behavior is somewhat implicitly documented when the manual talks about outer joins: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55323

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this without aliases.  The result of the "joined" query has two fields, both named a_id.  Unless you alias one (or both), as you did in your final query, the outer query has no idea which a_id you are referring to.

Why is your final query not a "perfect" solution?

Comment: I would add that `SELECT *` is typically considered a lazy approach - just list the fields you need, even if it's all of them.

Comment: If you trully need all columns, is there any benefit of not using asterisk performance-wise? I did not consider it perfect because I have a habit to always look for nicer solutions.

Comment: It actually can be done without using an alias - but only if the join columns have the same name (but if they don't the problem doesn't arise)

Comment: There shouldn't be a performance difference at all.  During compilation, * is extrapolated to all columns anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use alias as below:

```
WITH JOINED AS (
    SELECT A.A_ID A_A_ID, B.A_ID B_A_ID,
    A.FIELD_NAME1 A_FIELDNAME1, A.FIELDNAME2 A_FIELDNAME2,A.FIELDNAME_N A_FIELDNAME_N,
    B.FIELD_NAME1 B_FIELDNAME1, B.FIELDNAME2 B_FIELDNAME2,B.FIELDNAME_N B_FIELDNAME_N,
    FROM TABLE_A A 
    JOIN TABLE_B B ON (A.A_ID = B.A_ID)
)
SELECT A_A_ID, B_A_ID
FROM JOINED
```

IT IS ALWAYS A GOOD PRACTICE TO AVOID USING `SELECT *`

Comment: @AlexPoole: Yeah, but in third query A.* and B.* is used. I am trying to avoid the '*' and explicitly specifying the col names instead